# Is there any NOT operator in DCG

Tags: prolog, dcg

I think the question is clear from the title, I couldn't find any documentation about the NOT operator in DCG, while it exists in prolog.
Is there anyway to do it? Any example?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is one in many implementations, but its meaning is a bit problematic.  Instead, one uses rather negation within `{...}`

Comment: Show an example of how you wish to use it.

Comment: I can not think of a situation why you need NOT operator in DCG. Can you please let me know, why we need NOT in DCG?